# Loading a new HTML page with $http request

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm dealing with tokens, and with every HTTP request, the token will be added to the header so the server can tell if user is logged in or not.

Because of that, I can't redirect to the specific URL and check for tokens because the token wont be added to the header.

Is it possible to load in a new HTML page from an http request? Every time the server responds, I get the code of the HTML page. I think angular doesn't reload the new incoming page.

Edit: Here is some code

Code that adds to every http request

```
// ===================================================
// application configuration to integrate token into requests
// ===================================================
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken) {

var interceptorFactory = {};

// this will happen on all HTTP requests
interceptorFactory.request = function(config) {

    // grab the token
    var token = AuthToken.getToken();

    // if the token exists, add it to the header as x-access-token
    if (token) {
        config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
    }

    return config;
};

// happens on response errors
interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response) {

    // if our server returns a 403 forbidden response
    if (response.status == 403) {
        AuthToken.setToken();
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    // return the errors from the server as a promise
    return $q.reject(response);
};
    return interceptorFactory;

});
```

I'm using ui-routing. I have a front-end and back-end of the site. So when a user logs in from the front end, the front-end.html goes away, and back-end.html gets loaded. But angular just reads the back-end.html code.

```
// function to handle login form
vm.doLogin = function() {
    vm.processing = true;
    //clear the error
    vm.error = '';

    Auth.login(vm.loginData.email, vm.loginData.password)
        .success(function (data) {
            vm.processing = false;
            // if a user successfully logs in, redirect to main application
            if (data.success)
                return $http.get('/account');
                //Here is where a user logs in and i redirect them to the backend of the site. But the response is the HTML code of the page. I want that page to load.
            else 
                vm.error = data.message;
        });
};
```

Comment: Where is your code at? What do you mean the token won't be added to the header? Are you storing the token client side add adding it to `$http.defaults.headers.common`?

Comment: updated with relevant code

Comment: @StevenR Are you trying to implement fix for cross site scripting ?

Comment: @pratikwebdev No, I'm actually trying to separate my website into 2 different sections. a frontend and backend, but backend has token checks to see if user is logged in to continue. so I can't directly go to backend URL cuz then they're will be no tokens.

Comment: @StevenR You could try saving `token` in session variable instead of `request header` and verify the same on backend. my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

You are heading for the wrong direction.
You should read this:
http://blog.thesparktree.com/post/75952317665/angularjs-interceptors-globally-handle-401-and

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and is more appropriate as a comment on the question — it is likely to attract downvotes.